# How to concatenates tensors by both two dims in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to concatenates tensors by both two dims in tensorflow.

For example, there is four tensors with 4 dimensions. All tensors is something like images in tensorflow, so each dimension means the followings : [batch_size, image_width_size, image_height_size, image_channel_size].

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_tensor_1 = 1*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_2 = 2*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_3 = 3*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_4 = 4*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])

image_result_wanted = ... # Some operations here

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run([image_result_wanted])
```

Without consideration about batch size and channel size(I mean to say, only with consideration about image width and image height), I would like to work out the following :

```
[[1, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 4, 4],
 [3, 3, 4, 4]]
```

Thus, `image_result_wanted`'s shape should be `(60, 4, 4, 3)`.

How should I deal with this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.concat` to concat the tensors along the axis needed.

Here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_tensor_1 = 1*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_2 = 2*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_3 = 3*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_4 = 4*tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])

try:
    temp_1 = tf.concat_v2([image_tensor_1, image_tensor_2], 2)
    temp_2 = tf.concat_v2([image_tensor_3, image_tensor_4], 2)
    result = tf.concat_v2([temp_1, temp_2], 1)
except AttributeError:
    temp_1 = tf.concat(2, [image_tensor_1, image_tensor_2])
    temp_2 = tf.concat(2, [image_tensor_3, image_tensor_4])
    result = tf.concat(1, [temp_1, temp_2])


sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run([result[0,:,:,0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Really have no idea how to do this in one line, so I've come up with the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_tensor_1 = 1 * tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_2 = 2 * tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_3 = 3 * tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])
image_tensor_4 = 4 * tf.ones([60, 2, 2, 3])

# make two tensors with shapes of [60, 2, 4, 3]
concat1 = tf.concat(2, [image_tensor_1, image_tensor_2])
concat2 = tf.concat(2, [image_tensor_3, image_tensor_4])
# stack two tensors together to obtain desired result with shape [60, 4, 4, 3]
result = tf.concat(1, [concat1, concat2])
```

Following code:

```
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(result[0, :, :, 0]))
```

results with

```
[[ 1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  4.  4.]
 [ 3.  3.  4.  4.]]
```

as desired.

Too late, haha :)